# How can I avoid a Memory Error using scipy.linalg.lstsq for large matrices?

Tags: python, scipy

I need to calculate the Mahalobis distance for many different datasets and I run into a memory error for the scipy.linalg.lstsq function for the largest of them.  Is there any possible way to use a slower function or chunk this part of the analysis?

I have 8 different CPUs and 32 GB of RAM. I can sometimes see the RAM usage hit 100% before the memory error (1st printed line), but other times only 1 or 2 CPUs hit 100% and RAM only barely gets to 40% before I get the Memory Error (2nd printed line).

When I get the error, the print statement gives me:

1123840 71836800 (8780, 16) (561225, 16)

1169920 103577856 (9140, 16) (809202, 16)

The shapes are the exact same shapes as the inputs to mahal Y and X.  Both arrays are float64 and I've tried reducing to float 32 but that gives me different results.  I've also tried np.around() on the input but that doesn't change the byte size.

```
def mahal(Y, X):
    """ Function translated directly from MATLAB.  Tested to give equivalent outputs.
    """
    [rx,cx] = X.shape
    [ry,cy] = Y.shape
    m = numpy.mean(X,axis=0);
    M = m * numpy.ones([ry,1]) 
    C = X - (m * numpy.ones([rx,1]))
    Q,R = scipy.linalg.qr(C) #[Q,R] = qr(C,0)
    print R.nbytes, (Y-M).nbytes, R.shape, (Y-M).shape
    ri = linalg.lstsq(R.T,(Y-M).T)[0][0:cx] # For some reason, there are a lot of extra zeros that need to be removed
    d = numpy.sum((ri * ri),axis=0).T*(rx-1)
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

using least squares like that will result in an enormous intermediate matrix being created.  I don't have Matlab, but I can find the equivalent in [GNU Octave](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/statistics/file/tip/inst/mahal.m).  translating this into Python gives:

```
import numpy as np

def mahal(Y, X):
    xr, xc = X.shape
    yr, yc = Y.shape

    assert xc == yc, "X and Y must have the same number of columns"

    mu = np.mean(X, 0)
    x = X - mu
    y = Y - mu

    w = x.T @ x
    w /= xr - 1

    w = y @ np.linalg.pinv(np.linalg.cholesky(w).T)

    return np.einsum('ij,ij->i', w, w)
```

the GNU Octave code also includes some tests, which we can check:

```
X = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]])

assert np.allclose(mahal(X, X), [1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5])
assert np.allclose(mahal(X, X+1), [7.5, 7.5, 1.5, 13.5])
```

which succeeds for me.  next we can test that using big matrices, as you were doing, gives an answer in a sensible amount of time:

```
X = np.random.rand(561225, 16)
Y = np.random.rand(809202, 16)

mahal(Y, X)
```

runs the `mahal` function in 180ms

I'm using Python 3.5 [`@` syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) for matrix multiplication, you'd need to change this if you're using an ancient version of Python.